# Terraform destroy from GitHub Action is not working

Tags: azure, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-azure

I have setup terraform for Azure infrastructure but was not able to set a workflow where I can trigger destroying of the infrastructure created using Terraform Plan/Apply.

After trigger git action job terraform apply , resources has been created. But It doesn't destroy the resources. below is the error message:

> Run terraform destroy -auto-approve /home/runner/actions-runner/_work/_temp/5ea6e56c-8668-4081-8f1c-0dede09ee5a2/terraform-bin destroy -auto-approve No changes. No objects need to be destroyed. Either you have not created any objects yet or the existing objects were already deleted outside of Terraform

```yaml
name: infrastructure-setup

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  AKS-Cluster-Deployment:
    runs-on: runner1

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: terraform

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2.0.2
        with:
          terraform_version: latest
 #         cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TFC_TOKEN_ID }}

      - name: Azure login
        run: |
         echo "logging into Azure ..."
          az login --service-principal -u ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID  }} -p ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }} --tenant ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          echo "setting subscription ..."
          az account set -s ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
 

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init
      
      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: terraform plan
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Terraform Plan Status
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'failure'
        run: exit 1

      - name: Terraform Destroy
        run: terraform destroy -auto-approve
  
   #   - name: Terraform Apply
    #    run: terraform apply -auto-approve

#      - name: Terraform Output
#        run: terraform output
```

I am trying to delete the resources from a GitHub Action via the terraform destroy command.

Comment: Are you running the terraform commands in the correct directory after cloning the repo?

Comment: yes, I have mention the directory name in my git action code as well.

Comment: Ah ok. There is actually no `terraform apply` step so there is nothing to destroy.

Comment: `No objects need to be destroyed` ... For the record that is not an error message, just the output ... everything was previously destroyed or nothing was ever created ... I'm assuming you are using a remote state: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/remote if not successive runs will not know anything about what happened before

Comment: Can you share some of your TF code like the `provider` and `backend` blocks and some of those resources you created

Comment: @HelderSepulveda : I didn't created the backend.tf earlier. After Intiating backend.tf I am getting another error. Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).
│ 
│ To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal'

Comment: @MarkoE After terraform apply , I comment out  and only try to run terraform destroy

Comment: @HelderSepulveda  Please find the code here https://github.com/deepti-pr/terraform-action/tree/main

Comment: There you go ... you found the error no `backend.tf` that will cause the issue you described in the Question ... the other error I'm not familiar with but the description seems clear enough ... a quick google search takes me here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/22034

Answer (score 1):

> Resolving Terraform Destroy Issues in GitHub Actions for Azure Infrastructure

I Agree with [Helder Sepulveda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599833/helder-sepulveda) with the insights provided.

The error message indicates that Terraform cannot find any resources to delete, which usually implies that the state file Terraform uses to monitor resources is not consistent with the resources it intends to manage in Azure. This can occur due to various factors:

1. **Terraform's state file does not match the actual infrastructure in Azure**, because resources were deleted or modified outside of Terraform.
2. **The GitHub Action cannot access or use the Terraform state file**. This might occur if Terraform is executed in a different working directory, or if the state file is located remotely and Terraform is not set up to access it.
3. **Terraform configuration** or working directory is **invalid** in the GitHub Actions workflow.

#### Ensure State File Accessibility

- A **remote backend** allows you to store your Terraform state in a remote data store and share it with your team. To use a remote backend, you need to configure your GitHub Actions workflow to connect to it.

[image]

#### Add Terraform Apply Before Destroy (For Testing)

- Before you try to destroy any resources, you should make sure they are created first, especially if you are testing the workflow and it might not have created any resources yet. To do this, you need to comment out the `- name: Terraform Destroy` step and uncomment the `- name: Terraform Apply` step for testing. Once you verify that the resources are created successfully, you can switch back to test the destruction.

[image]

When you want to destroy infrastructure, you need to design your workflow according to the creation and destruction lifecycle. Usually, you would use different workflows or conditional steps for creating (`terraform apply`) and destroying (`terraform destroy`) resources. But if you want to create and destroy resources in one run, you need to make sure that the `terraform apply` step runs and completes successfully before you try to run `terraform destroy`.

***Reference:***

[State: Remote Storage | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/remote)

[Support for authentication through az cli with service principal · Issue #22034 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm (github.com)](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/22034)

[Automate Terraform with GitHub Actions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/automation/github-actions)